# How to positionate a tool bar at the bottom of a div?

Tags: html, css, positioning

I've problems with a stupid div :) I'm developing a website similar to twitter for a course but i've problems positionating the tools bar (retweet, delete...)

My tweet div is this:

```
<div class="tweet">
    <img width="50px" height="50px" src="img/profiles/mannuk.png">
    <p>
        <span>mannuk</span><br>
        This is my first tweet that i've sent with my twitter. RT if you like it #firstTweet
    </p>
    <div class="tools">
        <a href="#retweet">Retweet</a>
        <a href="#delete">Delete</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the css3 code:

```
.tweet
{
    background-color: #1FCC84;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    margin: 2px 0;
    height: 100px;
    font-size: 0.8em;
}

.tweet img
{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

.tweet p
{
    display: block;
    padding-left: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.tweet span
{
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
}

.tweet .tools
{
    clear: both;
    position:relative;
    margin-top: 80px; 
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

I need to apply to the tools div a position whose origin is the tweet parent div but i don´t know how to do it properly because in most cases the origin starts under the img, but the left margin is correctly applied.

Now there are differences between a tweet of 140characters and a tweet of 20-30. The tools bar is not possitioning relative to its parent.

Answer (score 0):

Almost got it...look at my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bb7555/79Uzf/

Just set the top-margin on tools to bottom margin:

```
.tweet .tools
{
    clear: both;
    position:relative;
    margin-bottom: 80px; 
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to place the `tools` div relatively, you should try giving `float:right`. Else,if the position is fixed - try **[this solution](http://cssdeck.com/labs/cde4spxo)**

Comment: I think that your solution is quite close to the result that i expecte. But is it necessary to create the extra div? Why the tools div can't positionate relative to the tweet parent div?

Comment: The extra Div is the container - You can position any div/element w.r.t something else, hence if u encompass a container, you can position your div anywhere you want w.r.t that container.

Answer (score 0):

You have to improve your html structure:

I edit your jFiddle in that [way](http://jsfiddle.net/Pasia/Ry9jZ/4/)

NEW HTML STRUCTURE FOR REFERENCE:

```
<div class="tweet">
  <article class="detail">
      <img width="50px" height="50px" src=""/>
          <h1>mannuk</h1>
          <p>This is my first tweet that i've sent with my twitter. RT if you like it #firstTweet</p>
  </article>
  <div class="tools">
      <a href="#retweet">Retweet</a>
      <a href="#delete">Delete</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see i used the standard HTML5 tag `article`. Is best to use that for semantic reasons.

Then is best to create 2 different module in your tweet: 
1- The article-> the space where effectively your tweet and your informations are.
2- Tools and action section.

With that structure is simple to manage the CSS.

NEW CSS CLASS&ID

```
.tweet{
background-color: #1FCC84;
border: 1px solid #000000;
border-radius: 0.5em;
margin: 2px 0;
font-size: 0.8em;
}
.detail img{
padding:10px;
padding-top:5px;
float:left;
}
.detail h1{
padding-top:5px;
font-size:12px;
}
.detail p{
background-color:red;
width:500px;
margin-left:70px;
}
.tools{
margin-left:70px;
margin-bottom:5px;
}
```

Hope you enjoy! ;)

Comment: Thanks @Riccardo you've shown an interesting point of view changing the syntax of the html. But the behaviour is the same that i have in my example. It works ok when the tweet text does not disturb the tool bar but when the text is bigger or you change the width of the browser window, the text and the tools overflow the tweet div

Comment: Thank you @Riccardo i will check it later. By the way.. do you have a reading about the new html5 elements? Because i don't know when i can use section or article instead of divs..

Comment: I've read a book, but I don't know where to find the same information online, try to google for it! [Book](http://www.peachpit.com/store/html5-css3-visual-quickstart-guide-9780321719614) I've an Italian version

Comment: Hi @Riccardo, the solution that you provided me hasn't got the expected behaviour. Because you change the width of the window and the text overflows to the right. Thank you in any case